# How to split 2 dates from a column and map to two diff fields using Python

Tags: python, pandas

Having a Excel file. The data originally is derived from email and doing a further analysis on the data, There is an [Dates] column where the dates are in the form of 1/10/2020 to 13/11/2020, We need to parse it into two different dates 1/10/2020 and 13/11/2020.

Input data:

```
Date
1/10/2020 - 13/11/2020
12/5/2019 - 16/5/2019
```

We need to map it into two different columns in another tab.

```
Date 1     Date 2 
1/10/2020  13/11/2020
12/5/2019  16/5/2019
```

what have been tried so far:

```
partitioned_string = a_string.partition('-')
before_first_period = partitioned_string[0]
after_first_period = partitioned_string[1]
```

But how to map the variable into two different columns in different tab.

Comment: Assuming your dataframe is named `df` then I believe you want `df['Date'].str.split('\s+to\s+', expand=True).set_axis(['Date 1', 'Date 2'], axis=1)`

Comment: If you want actual `pd.Timestamp` objects I'd add a `pd.to_datetime` like this `df['Date'].str.split('\s+to\s+', expand=True).set_axis(['Date 1', 'Date 2'], axis=1).apply(pd.time_datetime)`

Comment: @piRSquared    Date1 and Date2 columns are in another tab (Tab2) of CSV file, How it can be mapped .

Comment: csv files don't have tabs... you must be confusing your terms.

Comment: In real senerio .xlsx (Excel) file is being used where data is being store in 3 different tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split the array.

```
date = "1/10/2020 to 13/11/2020"

D1 , D2 = [date.split('to')[0]], [date.split('to')[1]]

print(D1)
print(D2)
```

Comment: [Manz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11050535/manz) Make sure and mark it solved, if your problem is solved. Then only others can easily get to know the different solution

Comment: How the values can be mapped to two diff columns in another tab.

Comment: You are splitting a single string and the same string twice `D1, D2 = date.split('to')` would be better.  But you came nowhere close to actually answering OPs question.  I'm happy to change my vote if I see improvement to the answer.

Comment: You can use a `for loop` to store under different columns